# Mongoose Default Scoped Query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Does mongoose support rails-like default_scope? For example, I'm adding an `isArchived` boolean field to my user model, but I don't want to update all my queries to select `isArchived: false` users. Is there a way to do this in mongoose?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in the mongoose docs but it should be simple to create your own scoping function that merges queries:

```
var defaultScope = {isArchive: false};

function scope(query){
    for (var s in defaultScope){
        query[s] = defaultScope[s];
    }
    return query;
}

Thing.find(scope({age: 21}), function(err, c){
    console.log(c);
});
```

It doesn't handle specifying the same property in both the default scope and query. Would have to add some logic to $and them.